# how to hide button when submit popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a BUTTON in my web page, if I click on the BUTTON,  bootstrap popover is come, in this popover submit button is there.  Now  how can i hide the BUTTON in the web page when submission of the popover.

Comment: Because you're using jQuery, you could `.hide()` the button (i.e. `$("query for button").hide()`)

Comment: show your onclick code here. And do as towerofnix said on your button click event

Comment: popover would just be some div in your mail HTML page, so you can access   the first BUTTON and hide it.. as said above. Put code for detailed answer.

Comment: i ahve tried   $(obj).parent().parent().parent().first().hide();

Comment: @towerofnix   i used .hde but problem is it search only in popover for the id i passed in jquery function, not in the webpage.. so we have to use parent method..but how...dont know...in my $(obj).parent().parent().parent().first().hide(); function it is closing div which the button contaied ...but not button